# Парсинг html: вытащить все слова

Tags: preg_match, php, парсер, html

Появилась проблема. Нужно спарсить хтмл и вытащить из него все слова, вот полурабочая функция:

```
preg_match_all("/<.+[^\/]>(.+[^<>])<\/.+>*/ix", $content, $var);
```

Но она не учитывает пробел перед следующим `<.+>`, также не может обработать, если вот так хтмл поставлен:

```
<div>First Text <span>Last text</span></div>
```

Помогите собрать правильный паттерн.

Answer (score 1):

```
strip_tags($str) + preg_split('/[\W]+/', $str)
```

А самое забавное то, что это решение гуглится за 2 минуты.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но проблема в том, что ваш вариант парсит и то, что в скриптах находится.

Answer (score 0):

по вашему примеру

```
<div>First Text <span>Last text</span></div>
```

решение

```
PATH = 'div'
div = g.cssselect(PATH)[0].text_content()
```

Ввывод

> First Text Last text

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/<\S+[^\/]>(.*?)<\/\S+>/ims', $html, $matches);
```

После `strip_tags` для элементов полученного массива.